# with atleast 60% marks in either of the degree examination-

Tags: grammaticality, meaning-in-context, ambiguity, sentence-meaning

a candidate must possess the minimum qualification of a Graduate/Post Graduate in any discipline from a recognized University **with at least 60% marks in either of the degree examination**: Does it refer to both graduate and post graduate marks or any one of them?

Comment: Tough to say without more context, but it would appear to indicate one or the other.

Comment: It doesn't look like valid English to me - to my mind, ***in either of the X*** requires that ***X*** be a plural noun form.

Comment: 'in either of the degree examination' is ungrammatical.

Comment: Yes. You are right. But this is officially notified by a company. I just copied and pasted here. I am not sure whether I am eligible or not. I have 60 % marks only in post graduation, not in graduation.

Answer (score 1):

**Either** is used to refer to a choice between two possibilities. In this sense, the OP's sentence is intended to mean either the graduation or the post graduation. But the sentence is grammatically not correct, because:

> **Either** must be followed by **of** if we use it before **the,** **these,** **those or possessives (my, your) with a plural noun:**
>
> ***Either of the children*** can come with us; we don’t mind which.
>
> *I don’t want **either of my parents** to know I’ve lost my job.*

([From Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/quantifiers/either))

Comment: @M - Well said. I would add another fix: "... at least 60% in either degree examination." For TOTAM, since you "have 60% marks only in post graduation, not in graduation," you have what they require. If they required both, they would use the word 'both' outright.